# How to open all the files in a directory, using terminal, in emacs?

Tags: shell, emacs

I've 4 java files in a directory, which I want to work with in emacs. How do I open them all with one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line:

```
emacsclient -a emacs file1.java file2.java file3.java file4.java
```

This opens the file in an existing Emacs if there is one and you have started the server (`(server-start)` in your `.emacs`). Otherwise this opens the file in a new Emacs instance. If you want to open all the `.java` files in the current directory, use `*.java` instead of the file names.

If an X server is available, you'll get a GUI Emacs window. If you want Emacs to run inside the current terminal instead, run

```
DISPLAY= emacsclient -a emacs file1.java file2.java file3.java file4.java
```

(`emacsclient -nw *.java` runs in the current terminal, but if there is no running instance then Emacs would start with a GUI).

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I'm now able to open multiple files in one Emacs instance.